# beautiful soup find_all doesn't find everything even with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have looked at most of the question on stackoverflow regarding beautiful soup only scraping half of the data from the website, but none of them have worked so far. I have tried changing the feature to lxml or html5lib etc. I also tried using selenium and now I tried to scroll the website all the way down using selenium to load everything on the website and use beautiful soup to scrape the data, but it keep only scraping 16 items when there is over 100 items needed. I have attached my code down below.

The link to the website that I am trying to scrape: https://www.ranker.com/list/kpop-disbanded-groups/ranker-music?ref=listed_on&pos=2

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import timeouts
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

url = 'https://www.ranker.com/list/kpop-disbanded-groups/ranker-music?ref=listed_on&pos=2'
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 3
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        html_content = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
        for years in soup.findAll('div', class_= 'gridItem_itemDescription__2Etxm gridItem_blather__2Mozw'):
            print(years.p.text)
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You might get more responses if you ask a question in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    params = {
        "limit": 200,
        "offset": 0,
        "useDefaultNodeLinks": "false",
        "liCacheKey": "decacb20-5d77-4b04-a871-7b2c54e3db15",
        "include": "votes,wikiText,rankings,serviceProviders,openListItemContributors,taggedLists",
        "propertyFetchType": "ALL"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params).json()['listItems']
    for x in r:
        yr = x.get('blather', 'N/A')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(yr, 'lxml')
        print("Name: {:<30}, Year: {}".format(
            x['name'], soup.get_text(strip=True)))


main('https://api.ranker.com/lists/2713714/items')
```

Output:

```
Name: 2NE1                          , Year: 2009–2016
Name: Wanna One                     , Year: 2017-2019
Name: SISTAR                        , Year: 2010–2017
Name: 4Minute                       , Year: 2009–2016
Name: I.O.I                         , Year: 2016–2017
Name: Wonder Girls                  , Year: 2007–2017
Name: X1                            , Year: 2019–2020
Name: T-ara                         , Year: N/A
Name: Miss A                        , Year: 2010–2017
Name: PRISTIN                       , Year: N/A
Name: IZ*ONE                        , Year: 2018–2021
Name: KARA                          , Year: 2007-2016
Name: Triple H                      , Year: N/A
Name: Orange Caramel                , Year: N/A
Name: After School                  , Year: N/A
Name: GFriend                       , Year: 2015–2021
Name: Pristin V                     , Year: N/A
Name: Nine Muses                    , Year: 2010-2019
Name: 2AM                           , Year: 2008–2017
Name: JBJ                           , Year: 2017–2018
Name: Boyfriend                     , Year: N/A
Name: HELLOVENUS                    , Year: N/A
Name: Sistar19                      , Year: 2011–2017
Name: UNB                           , Year: N/A
Name: Rainbow                       , Year: 2009–2016
Name: The Ark                       , Year: N/A
Name: History                       , Year: 2013–2017
Name: UNI.T                         , Year: N/A
Name: MADTOWN                       , Year: 2014–2017
Name: MYTEEN                        , Year: N/A
Name: Speed                         , Year: 2012–2016
Name: SPICA                         , Year: 2012–2017
Name: Stellar                       , Year: 2011–2018
Name: FIESTAR                       , Year: 2012-2018
Name: Secret                        , Year: 2009–2018
Name: B.I.G                         , Year: 2014- 2020
Name: Melody Day                    , Year: 2012-2018
Name: RaNia                         , Year: N/A
Name: C-Clown                       , Year: 2012–2015
Name: Hi Suhyun                     , Year: N/A
Name: BESTie                        , Year: 2013-2018
Name: Playback                      , Year: N/A
Name: HIGH4                         , Year: N/A
Name: Seo Taiji and Boys            , Year: N/A
Name: 15&                           , Year: N/A
Name: Glam                          , Year: 2012–2015
Name: CHI CHI                       , Year: N/A
Name: BIGSTAR                       , Year: N/A
Name: Coed School                   , Year: 2010-2013
Name: Bambino                       , Year: N/A
Name: 1Punch                        , Year: 2015
Name: EvoL                          , Year: 2012–2015
Name: A-Jax                         , Year: N/A
Name: Rainz                         , Year: N/A
Name: Leessang                      , Year: 2002–2017
Name: Tiny-G                        , Year: 2012–2015
Name: M&D                           , Year: N/A
Name: LIPBUBBLE                     , Year: N/A
Name: Homme                         , Year: 2010–2018
Name: Drug Restaurant               , Year: N/A
Name: 2YOON                         , Year: 2013–2016
Name: HONEYST                       , Year: N/A
Name: Jewelry                       , Year: 2001–2015
Name: D.Holic                       , Year: 2014–2017
Name: Lucky J                       , Year: 2014-2016
Name: M.I.B                         , Year: 2011–2017
Name: Tahiti                        , Year: N/A
Name: The Legend                    , Year: 2014–2017
Name: Wassup                        , Year: N/A
Name: Rainbow Pixie                 , Year: 2009–2016
Name: 14U                           , Year: N/A
Name: The East Light                , Year: N/A
Name: F-ve Dolls                    , Year: 2011–2015
Name: 8Eight                        , Year: 2007–2014
Name: 2EYES                         , Year: N/A
Name: Untouchable                   , Year: N/A
Name: DMTN                          , Year: 2010–2014
Name: Baby V.O.X                    , Year: 2013-2015
Name: LC9                           , Year: 2013–2015
Name: ChoColat                      , Year: 2011–2017
Name: CoCoSoRi                      , Year: N/A
Name: MyB                           , Year: 2015–2016
Name: I.B.I                         , Year: 2016–2017
Name: A-Prince                      , Year: 2012–2015
Name: M.Pire                        , Year: 2013-2015
Name: Bob Girls                     , Year: 2014–2015
Name: Gangkiz                       , Year: 2012–2014
Name: TraxX                         , Year: N/A
Name: GI                            , Year: 2013–2016
Name: BTL                           , Year: 2014–2016
Name: SKarf                         , Year: 2012–2014
Name: T-max                         , Year: 2007–2012
Name: Sunny Days                    , Year: 2012–2016
Name: SeeYa                         , Year: 2006–2011
Name: 4L                            , Year: 2014–2016
Name: Blady                         , Year: 2011-2017
Name: Phantom                       , Year: 2011–2017
Name: Puretty                       , Year: 2012–2014
Name: Double-A                      , Year: 2011–2015
Name: The SeeYa                     , Year: 2012–2015
Name: D-Unit                        , Year: 2012–2013
Name: Unicorn                       , Year: 2015–2017
Name: N-Sonic                       , Year: 2011–2016
Name: Supreme Team                  , Year: 2009–2013
Name: GP Basic                      , Year: 2010–2015
Name: Shu-I                         , Year: 2009 -2015
Name: Big Mama                      , Year: 2003—2012
Name: N-Train                       , Year: 2011–2013
Name: NOM                           , Year: 2013–2016
Name: Ledt                          , Year: 2010–2016
Name: PARAN                         , Year: 2005-2011
Name: N.EX.T                        , Year: 1992-1997, 2003-2014
Name: Kiha & The Faces              , Year: N/A
Name: Rumble Fish                   , Year: 2003-2010
```

Comment: Hello αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη, thank you so much. I was wondering how you got that link:  https://api.ranker.com/lists/2713714/items? Because I had provided a different link above.